# Backtrack 5 r3 in vmware player not showing wlan0

Tags: wireless-networking

I installed Backtrack via VMware player in win8. If I am connected to the internet with wifi in win8 I can use the internet in BACKTRACK too.

When I type `ifconfig` it does not shows "wlan0" - it only shows "eth1" and "lo".

I did not have to enter the security key in Backtrack when it's connecting.

I want to know what is going on inside and I want to manually search the wifi range and want to manually enter the security key in backtrack. How can I do that?

No wireless range is showing. My network adapter "Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter".

I tried NAT and BRIDGED connections, neither shows "wlan0" or any wireless range.

Comment: I have removed all the **unnessary emphasis** and SHOUTING from your post. Also, you're talking about VMWare player *and* virtual box. Which is it? Edit your question.

Comment: am using VMware, can u give the answer for my question.